# How to read the contents of a .txt file, modify it, and display it as an html page on local host in web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I have tried to do this for hours on end with searching the web for answers but none of them produce the results I need.

Currently, I open a .txt file, read the contents and console.log() them in the cmd window. I need to figure out how to output these modified contents onto an html page on the local host.
I create a server at a local host address (127.0.0.1:xxxx) and create a web page where you have hyper text links. I user serverStaticFile() to give it the html file of that page will display they modified version of the .txt file.

I have tried saving the modified version of the .txt file into another .txt file that will be accessed by the html page but only the last line of the original .txt file is saved. 
I use lineReader.eachline() because I have to take some parts of the line and put it into another string and then output those strings as the finished product of that line.

```
lineReader.eachLine( // For every line in the song
'original.txt',
function(line, last) { 
    var string1 = ""; 
    var string2 = "";
            var string3 = "";
            var string4 = "";
    var stringLine = line;
    var skipSpaces = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<stringLine.length; i++){ // For every character in the line
        if (stringLine[i] == "["){ 
            // If the character is a '[', scan the line until ']' is found. 
            // Everything in between is for string1
            var c = "";
            var x = i+1;
            var chordString = "";
            while (c !== "]") {
                chordString += stringLine[x];
                x++;
                c = stringLine[x];
            }
            string1 += chordString;
            skipSpaces = chordString.length;
            i = x;
        } else {
            // If the character isn't a bracket, add that character to the string2
            if (skipSpaces > 0){
                // Pad the top line with spaces, unless they should be skipped due to a chord having been added.
                skipSpaces--;
            } else {
                string1 += " ";
            }
            string2 += stringLine[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(string1);
    console.log(string2);
            string3 = string1+string2;
            string4 += string3;

            fs.writeFile("chordpro.txt", string4, function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
               } else {
            console.log("");
            }
        });


    if (last) {
        return false; // stop reading 
    } 
});
```

string1 and string2 are the modified contents of the current line being read in the loop.
I save the modified line into one whole string, string3, and try to put all of that into another string that doesn't overwrite the previous modified lines. The problem with this is that it only saves the last line of the original .txt file in the modified.txt file.
I wanted to upload this modified.txt file into the html page which I have not figured out how to do.

Can someone please give me some guidance?

Comment: There isn't enough code here for me to really answer the question. My best guess is that you are only adding the current line from the original file to string4, causing the new file to only have the last line when it is written.

Comment: @DeepThought I have edited my question. It should be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your "chordpro.txt" file only has the last line of the file that's being read from is because for each line in the input file you are writing that line to the output file when you are finished. When you use writeFile() it will overwrite whatever is currently in the file. What you want to do is use appendFile() instead.

```
fs.appendfile("chordpro.txt", string4, function(err) {
  //..
}
```

Comment: How do I make it so that it doesn't overwrite?

Comment: using appendFile like my answer says.